# Microsoft SQL 2008 R2 / Office SharePoint Server 2007 индекс обхода

Tags: sql-server

Подскажите, как выполнить в Microsoft SQL 2008 R2 (если можно описать пошагово) следующие задачи в автоматическом режиме:

1. Сбросить индекс обхода.
2. Сжать БД после сброса индекса.
3. Настроить полный и добавочных обход (полный раз в 2 недели, добавочный 1 раз в 2-3 дня).
4. Просмотреть планы SQL– исключить пересечение планов по резервному копированию с обходом содержимого. Исключить пересечение плана по перестроению индекса (если он есть ) с обходом содержимого.
5. Выполнить полный обход.
6. Выполнить резервное копирование баз данных
7. Выполнить Shrink баз данных

Comment: Сразу уточню, я не специалист.

Answer (score 1):

Настройте план обслуживания. Если работаете из Managment Studio - идти в Управление-Планы обслуживания. Там есть простой и понятный конструктор. Все основные задачи обслуживания вынесены в отдельные задачи, для нестандартных есть выполнение SQL-запросов